# How can I scroll the webview's content by scrollview?

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I load an HTML page in webview, it can scroll the content by webview, but I want to scroll the root view. Any advice?

Here is my layout code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/layout_background">

        ...

            <WebView 
                 android:id="@+id/webView"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                 android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">
            </WebView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: For people to help you, the question need to be cleared. Your question is not clear. So why do you want to scroll the root view Or what do you want to achieve from scrolling the rootView? Because the view is scrollable anyway.

Comment: Putting a `Scrollable` View inside another `Scrollable` View is a **worse** practice.

Comment: Because I have other views, and the webview is not high enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all your views to get scrolled inside single scroller, there is a very useful library - [commonsguy/cwac-merge](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)

There is single condition you need o satisfy to use the code provided below. Remember, this approach towards your problem can be different but end result is exactly what you need.

**Conditions:**

1. This library can be used only with ListView.

Thats all, lets begin.

> Make your activity layout this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Create a new layout XML. Let it be named `viewWebView.xml` and paste
>   this code:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#767676">
    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Create a new layout XML. Let it be named `viewTextView.xml` and paste
>   this code:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello There"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> So, now we have to work with java file. Open your *Activity.java file
>   and usage of library is below.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
MergeAdapter mg = new MergeAdapter();

/**
 * Prgram your webview
 */
View web = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.viewWebView, null);
WebView web = (WebView) web.findViewById(R.id.webView);
//TODO: Code your webview!!

mg.addView(web);
mg.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.viewTextView, null));
list.setAdapter(mg);
```

**Things to Rememeber:**

1. Views under `MergeAdpater` will be added in the way you add views to it. In other words order of you `mg.addView(View)` will be order in which items appear in ListView.

Cheers! If you have any problem implementing anything or even adding library to gradle just let me know!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! It's very helpful to me

Comment: Do an upvote and accepts as an answer to let others know that it solved your poblem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the scrollable content inside the `RelativeLayout` above your `WebView`? You can do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#767676">
</WebView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/webView"
    android:background="#222222">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello There"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

    </TextView>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Because in my project, the webview must at the bottom of the layout